# Permission Denied (publickey) when using SSH

Tags: server, permissions, ssh, amazon-ec2

I have Ubuntu 20.04 running in VirtualBox as my control node.  I am using AWS EC2 instances (Ubuntu) for my remote servers.

Every time I try to ssh into one of my EC2 instances I get " Permission Denied (publickey) ". I generate the key with no issues, but get the error when I try to run

```
 sudo ssh-copy-id -i <key>.pub ubuntu@ec2-X-XX-XXX-XXX.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```

I'm really new to Linux and AWS altogether so I'm wondering if there's something misconfigured somewhere in my AWS instance.

Comment: Why you are trying with `sudo`? You probably generated them on your home (`~`, `$HOME`). List them with `$ ssh-add -l`

Comment: You have to copy the public key (not the private one) into the EC2 instances. The instructions are probably in the AWS help page.

Comment: @PabloBianchi    When I run the ssh-add -l I get 'Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.'   :/

Comment: `eval "$(ssh-agent)"`? [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17848593/4970442) [2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/48868/209677). I don't see the need for root privileges here.

Comment: Everything suggested by all networkers I know has already been implemented so it's tripping up more than just me haha.  Basically, how does one successfully ping their aws instance from outside the network? I have all my inbound and outbound rules set as suggested, I have my Network ACLs configured as suggested, I've visited my security group and my VPC to make sure thing look okay.   Still cannot ping the dang thing.